# Can we/How to access a grandchild component through @ViewChild in angular

Tags: angular

I have a Component, ChildComponent and a GrandChildComponent. I want the Component to listen to an event emitted by the GrandChildComponent in ngViewAfterInit of the Component. But my GrandChildComponent is not accessible from Component, when I try to access the GrandChildComponent  through @ViewChild. Is it not possible or is there any alternate way to implement this?

Comment: You are trying to make skip level components talk to each other via events and nested components. A better design would be create a service and inject it in all parties interested in communicating. You could create a `subject` in the service and publish a value to it from your `GrandChildComponent`. The `Component` can subscribe to this `Subject` and be notified.

Comment: You can not directly access grant child event. Either you have to take the help of a child or do as @ashish.gd suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need is inter-components interaction.

One way would be to hack your way around as you suggest and have the grandchild somehow get the event, but it would be cumbersome. And then what if for design reasons you want to change the relationship between your communicating components?

The idiomatic way to go is rather to have the components share information whatever their relationships in the templates.

Angular docs describe this very well in [this section of this page](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) (take a look at the whole page to have a better grasp at what I just explained).

Answer (score 3):

Since you can call a child's function, you can have the child call the grandchild's function. Not sure if it's the best idea, but it's possible.

**Parent:**

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child!: ChildComponent;

makeGrandchildDoSomething() {
    this.child.callChild();
}
```

**Child:**

```
@ViewChild(GrandchildComponent) grandchild!: GrandchildComponent;

callChild() {
    this.grandchild.doSomething();
}
```

**Grandchild:**

```
doSomething() {
    //grandchild special function
}
```

**Notes:**

- To use `@ViewChild` like this, the child has to be in the view.
- Angular 8+ may need: `@ViewChild(ChildComponent, { static: false })`
- Similarly, you could bubble up the return value using `@Output`